# rake db:migrate is not working - continuously pending

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rake, dbmigrate

```
>C:\rails_projects\sample_app>rake db:migrate
>-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
>   -> 0.5100s
>-- add_index("users", ["email"], {:name=>"index_users_on_email", :unique=>true})
>   -> 0.0170s
>-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
>   -> 0.0340s
>-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20120428165946, ["C:/rails_projects/sample_app/db/migrate"
>])
>   -> 0.0560s
>You have 1 pending migrations:
>  20120507063126 AddAdminToUsers
>Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

every time I run "rake db:migrate" this is what I get. The migration is continuously pending and I can't get it to go? I'm a newb and I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I figured it out. For whatever reason the "faker" gem was causing the problem. I commented out all the lines in the sample_data.rake file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For whatever reason the "faker" gem was causing the problem. I commented out all the lines in the sample_data.rake file and it worked.